# Multiply digits in list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a `list`:

```
lst = [[7], [4, 3, 5, 8], [1, 3]]
```

How can I multiply each element in `list` by it position like this:

```
[[7 * 0],[4 * 0 + 3 * 1 + 5 * 2 + 8 * 3], [1 * 0 + 3 * 1]]
```

And print answer:

```
answer = [[0], [37], [3]]
```

Comment: Side note: never name a variable after a built-in, e.g. use `L` or `lst` instead of `list`.

Comment: yes, it's just for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `sum` and `enumerate`:

```
L = [[7], [4, 3, 5, 8], [1, 3]]

res = [[sum(i*j for i, j in enumerate(sublist))] for sublist in L]

print(res)

[[0], [37], [3]]
```

Or if you are happy to use a 3rd party library, you can use NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

L = [[7], [4, 3, 5, 8], [1, 3]]

res = [np.arange(len(sublist)).dot(sublist) for sublist in L]

print(res)

[0, 37, 3]
```

Comment: `from itertools import starmap; res = [*([sum(starmap(int.__mul__, enumerate(u)))] for u in L)]` ;) Or even worse: `[*map(lambda u:[sum(starmap(int.__mul__, enumerate(u)))], L)]`

Comment: @PM2Ring, Wow, impressive! The epitome of convolution.

Comment: The 1st version is ok, but it's on the fringes of unreadability. The second one is dumb, because the lambda adds the overhead of an unnecessary function call on every list in `L`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution ...

```
a_list = [[7], [4, 3, 5, 8], [1, 3]]
new_list = []

for sub_list in a_list:
    sublistsum = 0

    for i, value in enumerate(sub_list):
        sublistsum = sublistsum + i * value

    new_list.append([sublistsum])

print(new_list)
```